# AngularJS generated nested lists behave not as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multi-level list programmatically generated using JavaScript and deployed using AngularJS capabilities.

The HTML is:

```
<style>

    ul {
        animation-duration: 4s;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    ul li {
        display: block ;
        cursor:pointer;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    li.groupCollapsed {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    li.groupExpanded {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    li.groupCollapsed:before {
    /*Using a Bootstrap glyphicon as the bullet point*/
    content: "\e080";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: blue;
    }
    li.groupExpanded:before {
    /*Using a Bootstrap glyphicon as the bullet point*/
    content: "\e114";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: red;
    }
</style>

<compile-Directive id="cmpldirective" content="Commands_Tree_Contents"></compile-Directive>
```

where `compile-Directive` is an Angular Directive to compile HTML that was generated by the JavaScript. This works perfectly and generates the following:

[image]

The whole code generating this is:

```
$rootScope.Commands_Tree = JSON.parse (
    '[                                                                                              ' +
    '   {"Type":"Group","Name":"Group_1","Contents":                                                ' +
    '       [                                                                                       ' +
    '           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_1","Action":"Do_1_1"},                          ' +
    '           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_2","Action":"Do_1_2"},                          ' +
    '           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_3","Action":"Do_1_3"},                          ' +
    '           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_4","Action":"Do_1_4"},                          ' +
    '           {"Type":"Group"  ,"Name":"Group_1_5","Contents":                                    ' +
    '               [                                                                               ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_5_1","Action":"Do_1_5_1"},              ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_5_2","Action":"Do_1_5_2"},              ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_5_3","Action":"Do_1_5_3"},              ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_5_4","Action":"Do_1_5_4"},              ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Group"  ,"Name":"Group_1_5_5","Contents":                          ' +
    '                       [                                                                       ' +
    '                           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_5_5_1","Action":"Do_1_5_5_1"},  ' +
    '                           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_5_5_2","Action":"Do_1_5_5_2"},  ' +
    '                           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_5_5_3","Action":"Do_1_5_5_3"},  ' +
    '                           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_1_5_5_4","Action":"Do_1_5_5_4"}   ' +
    '                       ]                                                                       ' +
    '                   }                                                                           ' +
    '               ]                                                                               ' +
    '           }                                                                                   ' +
    '       ]                                                                                       ' +
    '   },                                                                                          ' +
    '   {"Type":"Group","Name":"Group_2","Contents":                                                ' +
    '       [                                                                                       ' +
    '           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_1","Action":"Do_2_1"},                          ' +
    '           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_2","Action":"Do_2_2"},                          ' +
    '           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_3","Action":"Do_2_3"},                          ' +
    '           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_4","Action":"Do_2_4"},                          ' +
    '           {"Type":"Group"  ,"Name":"Group_2_5","Contents":                                    ' +
    '               [                                                                               ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_5_1","Action":"Do_2_5_1"},              ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_5_2","Action":"Do_2_5_2"},              ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_5_3","Action":"Do_2_5_3"},              ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_5_4","Action":"Do_2_5_4"},              ' +
    '                   {"Type":"Group"  ,"Name":"Group_2_5_5","Contents":                          ' +
    '                       [                                                                       ' +
    '                           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_5_5_1","Action":"Do_2_5_5_1"},  ' +
    '                           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_5_5_2","Action":"Do_2_5_5_2"},  ' +
    '                           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_5_5_3","Action":"Do_2_5_5_3"},  ' +
    '                           {"Type":"Command","Name":"Command_2_5_5_4","Action":"Do_2_5_5_4"}   ' +
    '                       ]                                                                       ' +
    '                   }                                                                           ' +
    '               ]                                                                               ' +
    '           }                                                                                   ' +
    '       ]                                                                                       ' +
    '   }                                                                                           ' +
    ']                                                                                              '
) ;

$scope.Act_On = function(p_Action) {
    console.log("Requested actions is: " + p_Action) ;
}

$scope.Expand_Collapse = function(p_Element) {

    var l_Element  = document.getElementById(p_Element) ;
    var l_Sub_Menu = l_Element.childNodes[1].childNodes ;
    var l_i                                             ;
    var l_One_Sub                                       ;

    hasClass = function ( elem, klass ) {
        return (" " + elem.className + " " ).indexOf( " "+klass+" " ) > -1;
    }

    if ( $('#' + p_Element).hasClass('groupExpanded') ) {
        $('#' + p_Element).removeClass('groupExpanded');
        $('#' + p_Element).addClass('groupCollapsed');

        if(l_Sub_Menu.length > 0) {
            for (l_i = 0 ; l_i < l_Sub_Menu.length ; l_i++) {
                l_One_Sub = l_Sub_Menu[l_i] ;
                if ( hasClass(l_One_Sub,'show') ) {
                    l_One_Sub.classList.remove("show");
                    l_One_Sub.classList.add("hide");
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        $('#' + p_Element).addClass('groupExpanded');
        $('#' + p_Element).removeClass('groupCollapsed');

        if(l_Sub_Menu.length > 0) {
            for (l_i = 0 ; l_i < l_Sub_Menu.length ; l_i++) {
                l_One_Sub = l_Sub_Menu[l_i] ;
                if ( hasClass(l_One_Sub,'hide') ) {
                    l_One_Sub.classList.remove("hide");
                    l_One_Sub.classList.add("show");
                }
            }
        }
   } ;
} ;

Build_Commands_Tree = function (p_Start_Tree) {

    var i              ;
    var Tempo = '<ul>' ;

    for (i=0;i<p_Start_Tree.length;i++) {
        if (p_Start_Tree[i].Type == "Command") {
            Tempo = Tempo + '<li class="show" id="' + p_Start_Tree[i].Name + '" ng-click="Act_On(\'' + p_Start_Tree[i].Action + '\'); $event.stopPropagation();">' + p_Start_Tree[i].Name + "</li>" ;
        }
        else {
            Tempo = Tempo + '<li id="' + p_Start_Tree[i].Name + '" class="groupExpanded show" ng-click="Expand_Collapse(\'' + p_Start_Tree[i].Name + '\'); $event.stopPropagation();">' + p_Start_Tree[i].Name ;

            Tempo = Tempo + Build_Commands_Tree(p_Start_Tree[i].Contents) ;

            Tempo= Tempo + "</li>" ;
        }
    }
    return Tempo + "</ul>"
}

$scope.Commands_Tree_Contents = Build_Commands_Tree($rootScope.Commands_Tree) ;
```

The wrong behavior comes when I start collapsing sub-menus; for instance, if I click on **Group_1_5** the tree becomes as follows:

[image]

As shown, **Group_2** is shown indented while it should be aligned the same as **Group_1**. If I collapse the whole **Group_1**, both are shown correctly (same indentation to the left of the page.

I can't figure our what is wrong with the generated HTML.

### Edit

Following is the compile directive:

```
.directive('compileDirective', ['$compile', '$parse' , function($compile, $parse) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr.content, function() {
      element.html($parse(attr.content)(scope));
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }, true);
  }
}
}]) ;
```

Comment: create a playable example on plunker or here with snippet maybe?

Comment: I *tried* to reproduce your code in a plunker, but without the code for your `compile-Directive`, I can't get the collapsable behavior to work, and can't really test my theory.  I suspect, however, that you are probably affecting your `</li>` and/or `</ul>` elements with your collapse logic.

Comment: @Claies, I added the code for the directive. As for your hunch, I guess you are right, but can't find where the error is or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: hmm, ok so your directive is building a dynamic tree of content with jQuery functions in it?  Even copying everything over, I'm still not getting the arrows or the collapse behavior.

Comment: ok I finally got a plunker with the code and bootstrap, I'm about to take a look at it now. http://plnkr.co/edit/BF8SQMPZxhyj1Ni6BLvR?p=preview

Comment: I added a few more tags;  I'm no CSS expert, but what I see is that your `li.groupCollapsed:before {` CSS rule is applying to `Group_2`;  when it's removed, `Group_2` lines up correctly, but you lose the arrow.

Comment: @Claies, I change the CSS such that the glyphicons are `float:right` instead of `left` and it also makes it work correctly. This makes me think that there nothing wrong with the `<il>` / `</il>` (or `ul`) wrapping. What do you think?

Comment: I was about to post that I thought it had to do with the `float` property;  as I say, I'm not an expert at CSS but it looks like the `float` isn't actually necessary inside the `:before` rules.  the arrow seems to move up if the float is removed, though, so I was looking for a way to clear the float after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `float: left;` CSS property in your `:before` rules.

The `float` is carried over into the next group.  By adding `clear: both;` to the `ul li` rule, you can reset the float.

```
ul li {
    display: block ;
    cursor:pointer;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    font-size: 12px;
    clear: both;
}
```

[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BF8SQMPZxhyj1Ni6BLvR?p=preview)

Comment: Interesting!!!! Thanks man for the quick and simple solution. It indeed works are needed.